# How to find the probability of the sum of the faces of two dice.

Tags: statistics

I'm studying an introductory statistics textbook and it had this problem:

"Roll two fair dice separately. Each die has six faces. Let B be the event that the sum of the two rolls is at most seven. Find P(B)."

My question is if there is another faster way to solve this problem without listing all the outcomes that have a sum of at most 7?

Answer (score 2):

With only $6$ faces, I doubt that anything will be substantially faster.  If we have two $n$-sided dice, and we want to know the probability that a roll with total at most $n+1$ we could find a better way.

The rolls totaling less than $n+1$ are in one-to-one correspondence with the rolls totaling more than $n+1$ under the correspondence $$(i,j)\to(n+1-i,n+1-j)$$ so that the number of rolls totaling at most $n+1$ is sum of the number of rolls totaling $n+1$ and half the remaining rolls.  Since there are $n$ rolls that total $n+1$ we have $$n+{n^2-n\over2}={n^2+n\over2}$$ rolls totaling at most $n+1.$

Answer (score 1):

Another approach, which depends on $7$ being the average roll, is to note that the chance of more than $7$ is the same as the chance of less than $7$.  For any roll on the first die, there is one roll that gets exactly $7$, so the chance of $7$ is $\frac 16$.  The chance of more than $7$ is then half of what is left, or $\frac 12(1-\frac 16)=\frac 5{12}$ and the chance of $7$ or less is $1-\frac 5{12}=\frac 7{12}$